# How to fix OD diradmin account?

Tags: macos, osx-server, open-directory

I am unable to add new accounts nor delete existing accounts in Open Directory despite being authenticated as diradmin.  I can change existing user passwords though.  Tried rebooting, no change.  I was able to create and delete accounts earlier today.  The options to create/delete accounts are disabled in the OSX Server Mountain Lion GUI.

Suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this isn't too late, or that at least it is useful for others.

I tried http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1194 several times to no avail. I was simply unable to authenticate with the diradmin account.

An Apple support person recommended:

1. Archive the OD from the Server.app → OD panel → action menu → Archive Open Directory Master…
2. Select the server in the list and click on the minus button Once the OD has been destroyed, You will see the OD is now Off.
3. Create the OD by switching back to ON and create the OD again with the same information as before (including the DirAdmin)
4. Create a BackupDirAdmin account with WGM to have a backdoor, just in
   case
5. In terminal restore the archive you saved in step 1 using

> sudo slapconfig -restoredb < archive-path >
>
> Retest the authentication after the directory has been restored.
>
> Try as I might I couldn't get this to work, and then I noticed that in Mountain Lion server the slapconfig command had lost the -merge option so restoring the database was dumping both the new DirAdmin and backdoor account....

Bizarrely, after a lot of digging around I saw that mkpassdb has a -setadmin flag, so I tried to use this to elevate another slotId to admin rights. This worked, and then I was able to reset the password for the DirAdmin account.

Comment: Just make sure to quit Server.app and Directory Utility before step 5 in order to make it work… Hoping it's the last time I get that kind of issue while updating one of many OD…

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me at 10.10 Yosemite:

```
sudo ldapsearch -LLL -x -H ldap://127.0.0.1 -s base namingContexts
```

dn: namingContexts: dc=XXX-Produktion,dc=local

Put your dc= ,dc=  into this:

```
sudo ldappasswd -x -H ldapi://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fldapi -S uid=diradmin,cn=users,dc=XXX-Produktion,dc=local
```

Comment: Just ended up getting: Strong(er) authentication required (8). Did not work, no way around using this command line apparently

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that if you have enabled password policy, it applies when resetting the password, you can't re use the previous password and the change will fail.

Answer (score 0):

When Apple's `ldappasswd` approach did not work, I used:

`sudo mkpassdb -dump`

Which shows a number of lines but note the one with diradmin:

```
slot 0002: 0xe45670000668ce60000000b8b00025f2        diradmin   10/21/2020 05:34:35 PM
```

The slot ID is: `0xe45670000668ce60000000b8b00025f2`

and then using the slot ID, I reset the password:

```
mkpassdb -setpassword 0xe45670000668ce60000000b8b00025f2
```

without the failure of:

`Strong(er) authentication required (8)` I got from `ldappasswd`

Comment: That old wiki system is just so nice.  And for a wiki system with well over 500GB of data, there was no way to migrate without catastrophic data loss. Until the old 12 core MacPro tower dies, MacOS 10.6.8 just keeps on providing great service with the real "Server" software from Apple. Be forewarned, the current "Server" software from Apple is not even as functional as a lobotomized version of Server from 10.6.8